# NOt taking audio from MIC in android

Tags: android

I have created an app which will take sound from MIC and display its frequecy level in dB.

but when I am running the App,then error is coming in logcat.
`10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/ALSALib(2376): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2201(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM AndroidRecord_Speaker
10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/ALSALib(2376): external/alsa-lib/src/pcm/pcm.c:2201:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM NULL_Device
10-18 15:38:17.651: INFO/AudioHardwareALSA(2376): Initialized ALSA CAPTURE device NULL_Device
10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2376):  open (0,0x40000) = -2
10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(2376): setInputDevice(0 , 0x40000) = -2
10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/AudioRecord(3461): Could not get audio input for record source 1
10-18 15:38:17.651: ERROR/AudioRecord-JNI(3461): Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
10-18 15:38:17.655: ERROR/AudioRecord-Java(3461): [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
10-18 15:38:17.655: WARN/dalvikvm(3461): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
10-18 15:38:17.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
10-18 15:38:17.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461): java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
10-18 15:38:17.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:495)
10-18 15:38:17.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at com.android.spl.Recorder.run(Recorder.java:178)
10-18 15:38:17.659: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)`

Thanks
Please anybody help me...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in

startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.

Comment: See my codepublic void run()
    {

        AudioRecord recordInstance = null;

        // We're important...
        android.os.Process
                .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);//THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

        short bufferSize = 4096;// 2048;

        recordInstance = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, this
                .getFrequency(), this.getChannelConfiguration(), this
                .getAudioEncoding(), bufferSize);

        tempBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
        recordInstance.startRecording();